# How to do data modelling for a flowchart?

Tags: data-structures

I've a requirement to persist a flowchart built by users into database. Until now, I've been using BLOBs to store the flowchart image. But I want to serialize the flow chart and persist them as a structured data.

For example, a flow chart will have start and end, process box, input/output box, decision flow etc. All these elements will be connected by arrows. I'm blanking out on how to model data structure that will store this information. Any tips would be appreciated?

Comment: Q: Did my suggestions help?  Do you have a gameplan?  I agree - storing an "image" is probably of limited use.  But perhaps storing your .vsd?

Comment: Hi paulsm4@, thanks for taking time to reply. Your suggestion did help. I already knew that this can be done using XML. However, I wasn't sure how to model a flow chart. For example, flow chart has nodes and edges. Nodes can be of several types like start, end, process and can have constraints and after that, my brain is frozen. I'm reading documentation on BPMN 2.0 notation. I see that they convert images into a xml file.

Comment: Sounds reasonable.  Before you go too far with BPMN (which I know and love fromFileNet workflows ;)), download a BPMN editor and see if you can do what you want to with the format.  For example: https://download.eclipse.org/bpmn2-modeler/updates/oxygen/1.4.3/  or https://bpmtips.com/free-bpmn-modelling-tools-2018-edition/

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, but this question is too vague.

Perhaps the best question to start off asking yourself:

> Q: Do I really want to invent my own format, or find an existing "flowchart"
>   format that does what I need?

If you want to invent your own, I'd strongly suggest:

1. Using JSON or XML (instead of something completely ad-hoc), and
2. Finding JSON or XML examples for storing "graphs" (nodes, edges, etc).
   Here is one such example: http://jsongraphformat.info/

But then your next challenge would be how to *DISPLAY* your flowchat, after you've read it from the database.

ANOTHER SUGGESTION:

Assume, for example, you're using Visio.  I'd just store the .vsd in your database!